# Ubuntu won't suspend anymore, but it did upon install

Tags: 10.10, troubleshooting, suspend

I fresh installed Ubuntu 10.10 back when it came out, and my laptop was suspending fine. All of a sudden, I can't get my laptop to suspend anymore. It's an HP Pavilion dv2-1110, but I don't think it's a hardware issue, here's why:

- It suspended fine upon first install. I haven't installed any new kernels since then, but I have installed tons of packages, so it's probably a package.
- The suspend and hibernate options disappeared from the shutdown menu. If I press my keyboard's suspend button (or if I close the lid) I get the following message:
  [image]
- If I try the command `pmi action suspend`, I get the error message: `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files`.
- If I try the command `echo -n mem > sudo /sys/power/state` I get absolutely no output and no visible effect.

What might be causing this behavior? I thought a list of installed packages might be useful, but it's huge and I don't know how to post it here in collapse/expand mode or something.

EDIT:Just in case someone asks, none of the installed packages are kdm or anything like that (which would justify the lack of options in gnome's shutdown menu).

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Reported here and on forum as well but didn't get any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Software center and type 'acpi-support' in the search bar. Make sure, that the package is installed. 
Reboot, and voilà: suspend and hibernate are back and working again for me. Maybe this will fix it for you, too.

Answer (score 5):

Open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get install hal
```

Comment: could you please explain the command.

Comment: pmi action suspend message:Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files. -->sudo apt-get install hal

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late, but I am having the same problem as you.

It turns out `laptop-mode-tools` automatically removes `pm-utils` upon installation. I'm not sure why, but it would seem the 2 do not like coexisting.

Try installing pm-utils again with: `sudo apt-get install pm-utils`

For reference, I found this out from: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1660478

I hope this helps to solve your problem.