# What is the user-level command to suspend

Tags: suspend

(This was [previously asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line), but the solution no longer works under 11.10.)

In Ubuntu 11.10 any user can suspend the machine from the power menu in the top right of the screen without needing root privileges. How can I suspend as a normal user from a command line?

Comment: Under 11.10 the command `pmi action suspend` errors out with `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files`

Comment: That's a bug and should be treated as such ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind - I thought it may have been a bug of the "get it out of the repos" kind :P

Comment: I guess someone should create a .service file for org.freedesktop.Hal Noooooo idea how though :D http://askubuntu.com/questions/9518/ubuntu-wont-suspend-anymore-but-it-did-upon-install see the comment by zolti in his answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: Here's [the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/powermanagement-interface/+bug/800454)

Comment: yes and in the comments of my prev. link someone claims it is fixed by installing `hal` ;) might work for you too :D

Comment: @Rinzwind - `acpi-support` is already installed, and suspending from the menu works fine. I'm reluctant to install `hal`, though — AFAIK it's a legacy system. It can be a backup plan...

Answer (score 4):

There is a new answer to this at [How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line). You can suspend your machine (if it supports that) without any password by typing

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply \
    --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" \
    /org/freedesktop/UPower \
    org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

This works for me on Ubuntu 12.04. Credits to Adam who posted the answer over there.

Comment: This only works with root for me, on Xubuntu 13.04.

Comment: on 15.10 I get `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "Suspend" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.UPower" doesn't exist`

Answer (score 0):

Test your system if it supports the `pm-suspend` command with the following simple script:

```
for m in --suspend --hibernate --suspend-hybrid 
do 
  echo -n "$m: "
  if pm-is-supported $m; then echo "supported"; else echo "not supported"; fi
done
```

Sample output:

```
--suspend: supported
--hibernate: supported
--suspend-hybrid: not supported
```

If you have `--suspend: supported` you should be able to suspend your system with `sudo pm-suspend`.

Comment: Your answer requires `sudo` — please read the question again :)

Comment: You're right, although the test does not... but anyway I understand this is not what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this successfully with the powermanagement-interface package and "pmi action suspend" in 12.10.  Perhaps the problem you were having has been corrected in updates.

Answer (score 0):

Most functions in system dbus will need root power. So this should work well (tested on Ubuntu 14.04):

```
dbus-send --session --dest=com.canonical.Unity \
 /com/canonical/Unity/Session \
 com.canonical.Unity.Session.Shutdown
```

This may work too:

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager \
 /org/gnome/SessionManager \
 org.gnome.SessionManager.Shutdown
```

Install `d-feet` tool and browse DBus for all available options.