# Getting Error while doing suspend from the terminal

Tags: 12.04, suspend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu won't suspend anymore, but it did upon install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9518/ubuntu-wont-suspend-anymore-but-it-did-upon-install)

I am trying to put system into suspend from terminal with the command provided by the [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line)  but i am getting the following error

```
raja@badfox:~/Documents$ pmi action suspend
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files
```

Comment: i got it solved by the issue . you can close the question now .

Comment: Tell us how you fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kubahaha & other Friends Ok this is how i have fixed the issue ,

Open your terminal and do this

```
sudo apt-get install hal
```

then do as `pmi action suspend`

Issue won't arise again . Hope that helps .